# Argument of type '(e: MediaQueryListEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(e: Event) => void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I have created the following hook to listen to events:

```
const useEventListener = (event: keyof WindowEventMap, callback: (e: Event) => void, element: EventTarget | null = window) => {

  const callbackRef = useRef<(e: Event) => void>(callback)

  useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler: EventListener = e => callbackRef.current(e);
    element?.addEventListener(event, handler)
    return () => element?.removeEventListener(event, handler)
  }, [event, element])
}
```

Now I'm trying to create a hook that listens to media queries. However, when I'm passing down to `callback: (e: Event) => void` the following function `(e: MediaQueryListEvent) => setIsMatching(e.matches)` I'm getting an error from typescript. I'm struggling since `MediaQueryListEvent extends Event`! How can I solve?

```
const useMediaQuery = (mediaQuery: string) => {
  const [isMatching, setIsMatching] = useState(false);
  const [mediaQueryList, setMediaQueryList] = useState<MediaQueryList|null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const list: MediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery)
    setMediaQueryList(list)
    setIsMatching(list.matches)
  }, [mediaQuery])

  # ERROR HERE
  useEventListener("change", (e: MediaQueryListEvent) => setIsMatching(e.matches), mediaQueryList)

  return isMatching;

}
```

Full error:

```
Argument of type '(e: MediaQueryListEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(e: Event) => void'.
Types of parameters 'e' and 'e' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MediaQueryListEvent': matches, media
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error makes perfect sense with what you're struggling with ("MediaQueryEvents extends Event").  `Event` is missing a few properties that `MediaQueryListEvents`has (`matches` and `media`), so Typescript will complain about it.

If you'll only be using your hook with `MediaQueryListEvents` you can change the type from `e: Event` to `e: MediaQueryListEvents` in your hook `callback` argument (may require importing that type definition from whatever package you're using). If you'll be using a variety of different events, you'll either need to change it to `e: any`, or use the pipe operator to set multiple possible types for `e` (`e: Event | MediaQueryListEvents` and so on).

Comment: I think that the only solution is giving `any` type. It is not enough to set a or option for the type, since then the callback should still evaluate/cast the event to MediaQueryListEvent. I wanted to confirm that there wasn't any better solution that wasn't coming to my mind